# Dataflow job-id as a "lock" mechanism

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is it (would it be) possible to use dataflow job-id as a "lock" mechanism (be able to specify/lock job reference) - kinda the same way one can insert BQ job reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job ID is a unique identifier for a specific invocation of a pipeline. Since it is unique, using it as a lock won't work. suitable for use as a lock.

If you're trying to have one instance of a given pipeline running at a time, you can use the job name. Only one instance of a pipeline with a specific name can be running at a time (see [`getJobName`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineOptions#getJobName--)).

You can set the name with `--jobName=<some job name>`.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to get status of a job, either finished or currently running - given its `jobname`, or is it only possible with `job-id`?

Comment: It is not currently possibly to query for the runs of a specific job name. You can list all recent jobs and then filter it based on the job name -- for instance `gcloud alpha dataflow jobs list --job-name=<name>`.